# Compute variance of estimator with indicator function

Tags: probability

Consider two functions $E(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, and a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}$ distributed according to $P(x)$.

I am trying to compute the variance of an estimator for

$$ I(E) = \mathbb{E}[A(x)\delta(E - E(x))] \equiv \int_\mathbb{R} A(x)\delta(E-E(x)) P(x)dx$$

and relating it the marginal of $E$,

$$ P(E) = \int_\mathbb{R} \delta(E-E(x)) P(x)dx \ \ .$$

(the situation in which $A(x) = 1$).

Consider an estimator for $I(E)$ given by (*)

$$ Y(E) \equiv \lim_{\Delta E \rightarrow 0}Y_{\Delta E}(E) \equiv \lim_{\Delta E \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m f(x_i, E) $$

where $x_i \sim P(x)$, $f(x,E) \equiv A(x) \delta_{E(x) \in [E,E+\Delta E]}$, and $\delta$ is 1 if the condition holds and 0 else.

The expectation of $Y_{\Delta E}(E)$ is given by

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{\Delta E}(E)] = \mathbb{E}[f(x,E)]$$

and I suspect it converges to $I(E)$ as $\Delta E \rightarrow 0$. (*)

The variance of $Y_{\Delta E}(E)$ is given by

$$\sigma^2[Y_{\Delta E}(E)] = \frac{\sigma^2[f(x,E)]}{m}$$

My question is whether it is possible to relate $\sigma^2[f(x,E)]$ with $P(E)$ as $\Delta E \rightarrow 0$.

My intuition is that $\sigma^2[f(x,E)]$ should be relatable to $P(E)(1 - P(E))$ because when $A(x) = 1$, $\sigma^2[f(x,E)]$ corresponds to the variance of the indicator function $\delta_{E(x) \in [E,E+\Delta E]}$, which converges to $P(E)(1 - P(E))$ as $\Delta E \rightarrow 0$. But I am not finding how to relate them.

(*) I may be missing a $\Delta E$ somewhere.